# Null propagation operator and dynamic variable

Tags: c#, dynamic, roslyn, c#-6.0

I have been looking at the null-propagation operator in C#6 and tried to make it work with the variables of `dynamic` type but without success.
Consider the code below, it compiles but CLR throws `AccessViolationException` at runtime when the null-propagation is applied to dynamic object.

```
class SomeType
{
    public object SomeProperty { get; set; }

    static void Main()
    {
        var obj = new SomeType() { SomeProperty = "ABCD" };

        var p1 = ((dynamic)obj).SomeProperty;   //OK, p1 is set to "ABCD"
        var p2 = ((dynamic)obj)?.SomeProperty;  //AccessViolationException

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

At first I thought that this might be a bug but then I thought about `struct`s. Normally you can't apply `?.` operator to a value type variable (because it cannot be null). But you can cast it to `dynamic` and then apply the operator. So I changed `SomeType` to be `struct` and got the same exception.

The question is, it is by design that null-propagation for dynamic variables always is going to throw exception because the underlying object may be a value type?

The `AccessViolationException` is pretty ugly anyway, do you get the same one when you run the code?

Comment: Just a stab in the dark: what happens if you make `SomeType` `public` instead of `internal`?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Output is the same

Comment: If you run `PEVerify.exe` against your exe, does it report any errors?

Comment: @latkin ConsoleApplication7.SomeType::Main][offset 0x000000B2][found ref 'System.Func`3[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,System.Object,System.Object]'][expected ref 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite'] Unexpected type on the stack. ...

Comment: That's a compiler codegen bug, then. Please log it at https://roslyn.codeplex.com/WorkItem/Create

Comment: this has been fixed in the change http://roslyn.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/345430ed2dfce55bdfe71dc8754cace33ad242be

Answer (score 3):

AccessViolationException is almost always either a compiler bug or a mal-formed PInvoke call.