# Null propagation operator and Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.3 exception

Tags: c#, json.net

I have installed "Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.3"

and there are two methods:

```
    public static bool IsNull_yes(dynamic source)
    {
        if (source.x == null || source.x.y == null) return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static bool IsNull_exception(dynamic source)
    {
        if (source.x?.y == null) return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Then I have program:

```
        var o = JObject.Parse(@"{  'x': null }");

        if (IsNull_yes(o) && IsNull_exception(o)) Console.WriteLine("OK");

        Console.ReadLine();
```

- When program calls IsNull_yes method then result is "true"
- When program calls IsNull_exception then result is exception:
  Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' does not contain a definition for 'y''

Is it Newtonsoft.Json or other bug?

Comment: Y is not defined

Comment: Why "y" is checked when source.x == null? In IsNull_yes method we have the same: we check first part and when it is true we doesn't check another part in logical expression. Where are differences?

Comment: Change source.x?.y to source.x  in isNullexception

Comment: If I will change source.x?.y to source.x I get the same method as IsNull_yes, but question is about C# behavior: why C# null propagation operator works different as smt. == null?

Comment: Using dotPeek reveals that use of the `?.` operator on dynamic results in [non-trivial code](https://gist.github.com/nonnb/7723264ecb61cda9cb8bb22c84275047) as compared to the case of using the `?.` operator on a strong type. There have been [previous reports](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24194790/314291) of the Elvis operator not playing nicely with dynamic.

Comment: Closely related if not duplicate: [Null-coalescing operator returning null for properties of dynamic objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29051663/3744182).

Comment: Yep very closely related @dbc .

Comment: Hi, yes, this is helpful

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that `source.x` is ['sort of'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sort%20of) null.

To see this, change the code as following:

```
public static bool IsNull_exception(dynamic source)
{
    var h = source.x;  
    Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(null, h));   // false
    Console.WriteLine(null == h);                         // false  
    Console.WriteLine(object.Equals(h, null));            // false
    Console.WriteLine(h == null);                         // true

    if (source.x?.y == null) return true;
    return false;
}
```

You will note that `false` is written three times, then `true`. As such, the equality comparison used by `dynamic` is not the same as that used by `object.Equals` etc. *See @dbc's [awesome post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29053805/34092) for more details.*

Unfortunately, since it is not **really** equal, null propagation doesn't kick in (since null propagation does not use the `h == null` style comparison).

As such the equivalent `IsNull_yes` implementation is **not** your existing code -
 but something closer to:

```
public static bool IsNull_yes(dynamic source)
{
    if (null == source.x || source.x.y == null) return true;
    return false;
}
```

which acts exactly the same way (i.e. throws an exception).

Answer (score -1):

my guess is compiler must be checking if `source.x?.y` is still valid by looking at json string `@"{  'x': null }"`. As compiler has to verify if y exists in case 'x' is really valid non-null reference, it throws RuntimeBinderException.

Comment: If it is at runtime, I am confused why the compiler would be involved?